# Are Gaur Brahmins historically/traditionally Shaivites, Shakta, Smarta or Vaishnavites?

Tags: history, genealogy, sampradaya

I am from a Gaur Brahmin family (Specifically Gautam Brahmins from my dad's side, from my mom's side - she had the Jamdagni Gotra before marriage - don't think she is among the Gaur Brahmins). I was recently listening to Advocate J. Sai Deepak talking about sampradayas and now I am trying to find which sampradaya we are related to so I can reconnect to my roots. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try and Ask the elders in family abt your Kul Devata/Devi, they are the deity's your ancestors have been worshipping since ancient times As it can be quite difficult to find someone from the same lineage in such a small community:_)